# Datetime class is not working properly

Tags: .net, datetime

my controll

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateProduct(Products product)
/////
 product.Date = new DateTime().ToUniversalTime().ToString();
////
}
```

daty type is varchar in DB.

Why result time = 01.01.0001 0:00:00.

Where real time??

Comment: You didn't ask for the current time. You created an empty instance, which by default has the minimum value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

More Datetime [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: product.Date = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss") good it-Work, thank for reference.

Comment: Sorry! But my reputation can't use it. But I am very grateful!

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `DateTime.Now` to get the current time. Parameterless constructor of DateTime creates an instance with the minimum value.